# How to convert a PHP DOMElement into a PHP DOMNodeList

Tags: php, xml, dom, domdocument

I have a situation where I have a little function like below...

```
public function childUpdate($nodes, $newValue) {
    //Update values of each node
    foreach ($nodes as $child) {
        $child->nodeValue = $newValue;
    }
}
```

**This works perfectly whenever my function is sent a `DOMNodeList` but occasionally it can be sent a `DOMElement` instead.**

**This is a problem as in that situation, the `foreach ($nodes as $child) {` line fails as `foreach` does not work on a single element, and requires a list.**

So my question is -- is there an elegant way to quickly convert a  `DOMElement` into a `DOMNodeList` with just that one element inside it?

The obvious first thought  is to wrap the `DOMElement` inside an array like `array(DOMElement)`, and while that works for this function above, it does fail in other situations where I rely on `DOMNodeList` specific features.

**A simple way to convert `DOMElement` into a `DOMNodeList` would really simplify my code and remove a lot of "if 'element' do this, this 'list' do that" conditions.**

Answer (score 1):

Having the same problem.

With advice from:
[How to add elements to DOMNodeList in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27200556/how-to-add-elements-to-domnodelist-in-php)

Create a DOMDocument, add the DOMElement to it, and get childNodes which is a DOMNodeList

```
if(!property_exists($data,'length')) {
  $doc = new DOMDocument();
  $elem = $doc->importNode($data);
  $doc->appendChild($elem);
  $nodeList = $doc->childNodes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a DOMXPath for the document, you can use

```
 $nodeList = $xpath->query(".", $node);
```