# PHP DOM perform xpath query on DOMNodeList

Tags: php, dom

Is there a way to perform an xpath query on a DOMNodeList obtained by a previous xpath query? Concretely, I have the following code:

```
$topicMap = new DOMDocument();
$topicMap->load('topicMap.xml');
$xpath = new DOMXpath($topicMap);
$relations = $xpath->query("/topicMap/relations");
```

Now, from the resulting DOMNodelist `$relations`, I would like to select various subsets, depending on the `@type` attribute of the `relations` elements. I tried to supply the DOMNodeList as a second argument (i.e., context node) to a second xpath query, like so:

```
$relations_translation = $xpath->query("/*[@type='translation']", $relations)
```

I am receiving the following error: `Argument 2 passed to DOMXPath::query() must be an instance of DOMNode, instance of DOMNodeList given`.

I know that I could perform the two queries in one step, i.e., `$relations_translation = $xpath->query("/topicMap/relations[@type='translation']")`. The reason why I would like to do it in two steps is performance. The xml document topicMap.xml is very large, the set of `relations` elements a small part of it, and the number of queries that I need to perform on this set also relatively large. So I am thinking that it will be faster to traverse the large xml document only once, select the `relations` elements, and then perform the various queries on this much smaller list of nodes. I don't know yet whether it will be faster, but I would like to try. Is there a way to do what I want to do?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You will need to loop on the returned domlist. Also , use a relative search the second time :  .[@type=…   .

Comment: @PtitXav: Thanks for the quick reply! I thought about looping through the DOMNodelist, but see the following problem with this approach: I need the `relations` of a certain `@type` as a DOMNodelist which I can, then again, loop through and process. And I don't see how, by looping through the original DOMNodeList, I can collect a certain subset of it in a DOMNodelist.

Comment: [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27200556/how-to-add-elements-to-domnodelist-in-php) may help you

Answer (score 0):

Following the suggestion by Ptit Xav, I came up with the following solution:

```
$topicMap = new DOMDocument();
$topicMap->load('topicMap.xml');
$xpath = new DOMXpath($topicMap);
$relations = $xpath->query("/topicMap/relation");

$translations = array(); // and analogously for other types of relation
foreach ($relations as $item) {
   if ($item->getAttribute("type") == "trans") {
      $translations[] = $item; 
   }
   // and analogously for other types of relation
}
```

That is, I loop through the `$relations`, check for the `@type` attribute and then store the relations according to their type in predefined arrays.